# How to do Monte Carlo Method for exceedingly large numbers?

Tags: monte-carlo, simulation, calculator

For a paper I'm writing for my math class, I need to do several Monte Carlo simulations for a game I'm playing. The $p=0.6190411273$, a normal number... but the $n=2.14974(10^{10})$. I've tried to run a simple Monte Carlo simulation on my TI-84, but it flat-out refuses to do a simulation that big. Does anyone know how I would go about doing a Monte Carlo simulation for such a large number of trials?

Comment: 1) Get the largest computing resources you can find (including multi-core machines), 2) Break the problem into portions of $n$, 3) Use optimized code.

Comment: Even if you can do a million simulations per second, this will take over 5 hours. What is the largest $n$ your calculator can handle?

Comment: It is difficult to give an advice without more information on the simulation. First try to find a solution at the algorithmic level